# Appending circle shape to Path2D

Tags: java, swing, awt, shapes, java-2d

So, to append a rectangle to a Path, you can do this

```
    Path2D rect = new Path2D.Double();
    rect.append(new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 10), true);
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
    Path2D circ = new Path2D.Double();
    circ.append(new Circle(... params) true);
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use an Ellipse2D and give it symmetric parameters.

e.g..,

```
circ.append(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h), true); // where w == h
```

To see all the classes that inherit from [java.awt.Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) please check out its [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html).

Comment: Easy as that...thanks a lot! Will accept after the time limit :)